# Syntax error, unrecognized expression after putting js code in a js file

Tags: javascript

I've this code in my aspx file which uses jquery-1.9.1.js, and the app runs fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=datepickerStart.ClientID%>").datepicker();
        $("#<%=datepickerEnd.ClientID%>").datepicker(); 
    });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="datepickerStart" runat="server">Start Date</asp:TextBox>              
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenDateStart" runat="server" />
```

When I put the js code in a js file like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=datepickerStart.ClientID%>").datepicker();
    $("#<%=datepickerEnd.ClientID%>").datepicker(); 
});
```

I got this error message:

Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

```
#<%=datepickerStart.ClientID%>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Suggestion : put your ASP code back in a file the ASP engine interprets.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding ASP.Net code in external javascript files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377294/embedding-asp-net-code-in-external-javascript-files)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP is not evaluating the file, because it's a javascript file. Put the asp back in the aspx.

Comment: If OP still wants to keep the code separate, target the class of the element in the separate JS file.